# javascript bundling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, bundle

i am using bundling js  . i can minimise the js file having regular functionality. but i struggled in one js file which is using "exports"  this is the function syntax having the issue

```
   (function fnName (exports) {

    exports.generateUUID = function () {//other codes}

}(typeof exports === 'undefined' ? this.fnName = {} : exports));
```

i think because of this syntax i am facing the issue . can anyone please help me to resolve this issue . i need to bundle this file also

Answer (score -1):

It is quite hard to know what you want. Perhaps this is simply because of your comment?

Turn `//othercodes//` into `//other codes`.

Comment: no,, actually i need to bundle (means minimise ) a file. beacause this type of syntax. bundling is not happening .i am using bundle js